# How do I search in multiple fields with ElasticSearch and a CURL request?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, field

How can I perform a ElasticSearch search on multiple fields, using a `curl -X GET` request?

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
 curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/foo/_count?pretty=true&q=user:foo AND posts:bar"
```

Also:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/foo/_count?q=\"user:foo AND posts:bar\"&pretty=true'
```

Problem is, I only seem to get this response:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params in the URI need to be [urlencoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) and should not include the escaped double quotes.

For example the query in OP should be :

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/foo/_count?q=user%3Afoo%20AND%20posts%3Abar&pretty=true`